# JavaScript animation with easing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a slider module with JavaScript. Everything works, but the animation is linear, and doesn’t feel smooth or natural. I had thought of hooking up an easing equation, but I'm not sure where it goes.

Here’s the animation function I borrowed [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11213374/704015):

```
function animate(elem, style, unit, from, to, time) {
    if (!elem) return;
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            var step = Math.min(1,(new Date().getTime()-start)/time);

            elem.style[style] = (from+step*(to-from))+unit;

            if (step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
        },25);
    elem.style[style] = from+unit;
}
```

And an easing function [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7347076/704015):

```
/**
 * @param {Number} t The current time
 * @param {Number} b The start value
 * @param {Number} c The change in value
 * @param {Number} d The duration time
 */ 
function easeInCubic(t, b, c, d) {
    t /= d;
    return c*t*t*t + b;
}
```

I tried just passing in the values I already have like this:

```
elem.style[style] = easeInCubic(start, from, to, time) + unit;
```

But  clearly, that’s wrong (I’m not amazing at maths, and I’m admittedly just guessing).

How do I join the two together?

Comment: You might be able to take an existing easing function from [here](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/).

Comment: Have you got a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your approach is ok, you just used wrong parameters.
as it says, t is **current** time and d is overall animation time

```
function animate(elem, style, unit, from, to, time) {
    if (!elem) return;
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            var step = Math.min(1,(new Date().getTime()-start)/time);
            elem.style[style] =  easeInCubic(step*time, from,step*(to-from), time)+unit;

            if (step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
        },25);
    elem.style[style] = from+unit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`t`is the current time, or more accurately the elapsed time. In your case `new Date().getTime() - start`

`c` is the difference between start and end, in your case `from - to`.

```
        var elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - start;
        elem.style[style] = easeInCubic(elapsedTime, from, to - from, time) + unit;
        if (elapsedTime >= time) clearInterval(timer);
```